# Is it true that $\omega = \sum_{(k,l)\in I^2}\omega(p_k - p_l)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $\{p_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of projections in a $C^*$-algebra $A$ such that $\sum_{i \in I} p_i = 1$ in the strict topology (note here that $1$ is the unit of the multiplier algebra $M(A)$). Let $\omega \in A^*$ be a bounded functional on $A$. Is it true that
$$\omega = \sum_{(k,l)\in I^2} \omega(p_k-p_l)$$
where the convergence is in norm?

Recall that this means that
$$\lim_{F}\left\|\sum_{(k,l)\in F} \omega(p_k-p_l)-\omega\right\| = 0$$
where the limit ranges over all finite subsets of $I^2 = I \times I.$

Using Cohen's factorisation theorem, I managed to show that if $\{x_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \to 1$ strictly, then
$$\lim_{(\lambda,\mu)\in \Lambda \times \Lambda} \omega(x_\lambda - x_\mu) = \omega$$ in norm. I tried to use this but I end up with the following:

$$\omega = \lim_{(F,G)}\sum_{(k,l)\in F \times G} \omega(p_k-p_l)$$
in norm which is not quite what I want. Maybe if this norm-limit exists, so does the norm-limit
$$\lim_F \sum_{(k,l)\in F}\omega(p_k-p_l)$$
(in which case both limits must necessarily coincide, as one is a subnet of the other).

Any help is greatly appreciated!